# I can't get those variable declarations right...Why those parameters don't work? I just set the n value as arrays length

Tags: c++

I can't get those variable declarations right...Why those parameters don't work? I just set the `n` value as arrays length.

Why the compiler can understand the variable declaration?

```
void diag(int n, double a[n][n], double b[n],double x[n]){

    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        x[i] = b[i]/a[i][i];
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: please explain what is the meaning of "dont work", I bet there was a compiler error that already tells you why this is not valid code, no?

Comment: [Error] use of parameter outside function body before ']' token ..The compiler can't understand the array variable declaration (c++)...why?

Comment: please include the error message in the question

Comment: 4 [Error] use of parameter outside function body before ']' token

Comment: c++ has no variable length arrays. when you delare an array like `double b[n]` then `n` has to be known at compile time

Comment: 4  [Error] expected ')' before ',' token

Comment: you can edit the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54288223/edit)

Comment: I believe that would work in C, but C++ is not C.

Comment: Simplifying - just remove the `n`s from the arrays in your method signature...

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado `double a[][]` is not allowed in C++

Comment: true, true... need to swap to `*`...

Answer (score 1):

You have to use dynamic arrays (for example std::vector) or pointer on array. In C++ You can't use arrays with not known size at compilation time ('n' is not know).

Answer (score 1):

This is just not legal C++ or anything close to it. Arrays must have their dimension known at compile-time,  and if you pass one to a function, all dimensions except for the innermost must be specified.

Furthermore, the name of a parameter is not in scope for other parameter declarations. (which is what your errors are about).

If you want to use "arrays" whose dimension is not known at compile-time, you can use `std::vector` which is a contiguous resizeable array.